# Bulk remove a word from all WordPress URLs

Tags: sql, wordpress, url

I've imported about 600 pages into my WordPress database and most (not all) of them have the word "park" at the end of their new URL's

```
domain.com/awesome-park/
```

I would like to bulk remove the word (and its previous dash - )change them via SQL query or other recommended method. Any advice for a safe way to change URLs inside a database would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slug is stored in `wp_posts.post_name`. So the following should work (this from the first answer above):

```
UPDATE wp_posts
   SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name, '-park', '')
 WHERE post_name REGEXP '-park$';
```

I do recommend backing up your WordPress database before running this query!

Comment: This was an eipc snippet of SQL, thank you kindly. Any way to target only a specific CPT?

Comment: I believe you can just add `AND post_type = '<my_post_type>'`

Answer (score 1):

If you know the table and column where this url has been defined you could run next query:

```
UPDATE 'table_name' SET 'url_column' = REPLACE('url_column', '-page', '');
```

Answer (score 1):

This simple plugin can do the job.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/

Note : Remember you should only do this for wp_posts table and take a backup of your database before executing the query.

Comment: Thanks @Adeel but I don't trust that plugin. I'm going to manually edit them :(

Comment: I've used that plugin several times and it just works fine.. If you do it manually it will just take more time . I don't think there is so much to worry about a plugin having `Downloads: 613,807` and `4.4 out of 5 stars` , else your wish.

Comment: Sorry @Adeel to search and replace -word it wanted to replace the instance in 4 tables... I can't run that.

Comment: There is also an option to select individual table.